# Markers appear on folium map when clicking on button

Tags: python, dataframe, mapping, folium

I am implementing a map in folium taking the information from a dataframe df. I contains the longitude, latitude, name and region information.
Using a GeoJson file I have taken here: https://github.com/martinjc/UK-GeoJSON, I am able to define the regions in UK, highlight them when hovering with the mouse pointer and show some information. I would like to create a popup for each region with a button. If the button is clicked all the entries in the df which are in that region appear like markers. Is it possible? The code I am using right now is below:

```
...operations on df and definition of the map m...

width = 10
heigth = 4
resolution = 75
def style_function(feature):
        return {
            'fillColor': '#ffaf00',
            'color': 'grey',
            'weight': 1.5,
            'dashArray': '5, 5'
        }


def highlight_function(feature):
    return {
        'fillColor': '#ffaf00',
        'color': 'black',
        'weight': 3,
        'dashArray': '5, 5'
    }


c = folium.GeoJson(geojsonFile, 
                       name = 'Highlight',
                       overlay=True, 
                       style_function = style_function,
                       highlight_function = highlight_function)

html = '{}<br> Info:   {} <br> <buttononclick="window.location.reload()">Reload</button>'.format
frame = IFrame(html(name, info), width=(width*resolution)+20, height=(height*resolution)+20)
popup_text = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=2650)
c.add_child(folium.Popup(popup_text))
c.add_to(m)
```

I can add the button in the popup; what I am trying to do is to define a function like:

```
def testFunction(df, region):
   markerCluster = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(map)
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['region'] == region:
             folium.Marker([row['lat'], row['lon']], popup='some text').add_to(markerCluster)
```

that will be run when the button is clicked. The final effect I am looking for should be: open the map, click on the selected region, click the button, the markers on the region appear. But I haven't found any solution yet (I have tried with Flask without success).

Comment: hi were you able to achieve this, i am looking for a similar function to have mouseclick events on folium, can you please help me sample code. thanks